# An example of finding the longest path in DAG with both positive and negative weights

Tags: algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

I read that Critical Path Method uses the longest path method with positive weights and it is used for scheduling a set of project activities (time values must be positive).

In my case I need to find the longest path in DAG with both positive and negative weights. What can I use this problem for? I need an example.

Comment: [Does this help?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1185723/127998) "The argument that it works (i.e. that it in fact computes the total weight of the heaviest path ending at each node of the graph) does not depend on the weights being positive."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding longest path in a DAG doesn't really "care" about only positive weights, it is done using [Dynamic Programming (DP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Dynamic_programming) by following the formula:

```
D(target) = 0
D(i) = max { D(j) + w(i,j) | for each edge (i,j) }
```

The above is finding `D(v)`, which is the maximal length path that starts at `v` and ends at the target.

By going over the nodes in reverse order of [Topological Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), it is done in `O(V+E)`.

Note that the above doesn't really care if an edge is negative or positive, it's basically a brute force approach, that when implemented as DP, done more efficiently by not recalculating the same things multiple times.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with graphs, is it possible OP got negative weight confused with Pythagorean equality or whatever it's called? Is that even relevant?

Comment: @CaptainMan That's an issue with Dijsktra's Algorithm (triangular Inequality) for finding *shortest path(, but that's not an issue when dealing with longest path in a DAG..

Comment: @amit Ok, it's clear for me now, thank you. Can I use this method to calculate for example the maximum cost of realizing a project?

Comment: @czeski I don't follow your question I am afraid.

Comment: @amit I need to formulate some verbal real problem and map it as a DAG with negative and positive weights. Then find the longest path in the DAG.

Comment: @czeski There are lots of problems that can be used. A simple example is: You are a bus driver, need to get from city `s` to city `t`. Each road has some known value `w(u,v)` for the customers (beautiful roads will have more value since they make the customers happier). Some roads has negative weight since it makes the customers miserable to use them. You can only go torwards `t`, never back (so DAG). what is the path from `s` to `t` with maximal value?